# Problems looping in C++ with \n

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, newline

What I am trying to do is make a while loop that loops as long as "\n" is not entered. The problem is that it asks for my input once and then just ends. Here is my code

```
paliTester = cin.get();
while (paliTester != "\n")
{
   paliTester = cin.get();
}
```

Comment: ah, I just realized it might help to say the data type. its a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with your code, the problem is with the console that is providing you with your input. All consoles today provide a line editing option. Meaning you can type a command, erase part of it and rewrite as many times as you want. Until you'll press ENTER no input will be provided to the program waiting to read it. This means there's no way to provide any content to your program without pressing ENTER and ENTER means your program will  receive '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because \n is the new line escape sequence. Use "\\n" instead.
Also try this instead of get().

```
 cin >> paliTester;
 while (paliTester != "\\n")
 {
  cin >> paliTester;
 }
```

Comment: ah, I just ended up using a # instead, it saved me a headache.  also, i needed .get() because I was using individual letters for a stack :P